# How to know when puppeteer-cluster initializes a new worker

Tags: puppeteer-cluster

I have a gated website that I am scanning with puppeteer-cluster. I have a maximum concurrency of 5 with context_browser to share session information across tabs. This works great for the first 5 scans but once the worker dies and a new one is spawned, the session information is gone.

I plan to just run the code in chunks of 5 with the login script at the beginning. However, I wanted to know if there is an event that is emitted like "newWorker" that I can listen to like:
`cluster.on('newWorker, callback());` So that I can put the login script in the callback.

Any help is appreciated.